# Running program only when PC start up using WOL

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

Is it possible to create an event or script to launch when the computer is started using Wake-On-Lan?

I don't want to start the program (automatically) when the computer is started up normally.

Comment: There is no separate Windows event, if the machine is turned on with WOL, or turned on using some other means (power button).

Answer (score 4):

Here is my idea for creating such a trigger
(but I cannot guarantee success).
As I don't have the right environment for testing the idea,
some experimentation is required on your side.

The following command may be used to identify the wake source :

```
powercfg -lastwake
```

In the case of Wake-On-Lan (WOL), the reported wake device will be your
Ethernet controller.

Once you know that such an event has occurred and the exact name of the
wake source, this is my idea on how to add a trigger script :

1. Open up the Event Viewer and find the WOL event
   (where the wake source is the Ethernet controller)
2. Right-click the event and select "Attach Task To This Event..."
3. Select "Start A Program" as the Action
4. Add `Powershell.exe` and the path to your script
5. For more control, on the Finish step select the "Open the Properties..."
   check-box
6. In the Triggers tab, edit the event trigger to add more detailed triggering

Some references and examples to help in getting started :

- [Trigger a PowerShell Script from a Windows Event](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/)
- [Attaching Tasks to Event Viewer Logs and Events](http://techgenix.com/attaching-tasks-event-viewer-logs-events/)
- [Advanced XML filtering in the Windows Event Viewer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/)
- [Task scheduler – Event Log Trigger – Include Event Data in mail](https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/task-scheduler-event-log-trigger-include-event-data-in-mail/)
- [How to Read the Wake Source Log in Event Viewer](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/179257-wake-source-read-event-viewer-log.html)

Comment: This only works if the computer was sleeping, not when the computer is actually starting (from power ON). No solution has been found...

Comment: Have you searched all events whose source is the Ethernet controller?

Comment: There is no source named Ethernet controller. I searched from when the computer started, this event is shown: "The operating system started at system time ‎2018‎-‎07‎-‎27T06:28:13.494838200Z." (Kernel-General). But there are no events before or after indicating WoL startup. The only thing that can be found is: "The boot type was 0x0.", which means: cold boot from full shutdown. So sadly no indications if the computer started from WoL..

Comment: The source won't be named "Ethernet controller" but the name of the network adapter. Also, do you have events with source Kernel-Power?

Comment: I have events with the source Kernel-Power, however they are the same for WoL boot and Normal boot. There are no events on a network adapter around the time of boot.

Comment: Apparently this means that when totally shutdown, the WOL process is too hardware-based to be logged by Windows. So the solution may only work for sleep, where Windows is still in memory and in control of the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

As Ramhound already mentioned in the comments Windows has no way of knowing how the computer was turned on. (WOL, Bios timer event, manually switched on, and so.)

The only thing you can get from Windows is whether the startup of the computer took place after a normal restart or shutdown event or if the computer was started up after an unexpected power-loss or forced shutdown.
This information can be found in the event-log.

The best you can do applies if you know for certain that the WOL event only takes place in a time-frame that you would never be using your computer yourself.
You can setup a scheduled task to run every 5 minutes or so during that time-frame that runs a script to launch the application.
The task must be configured to NOT wake the computer up, so it only gets to run if the computer is woken by WOL. 
The script should basically check first if the application is already running (if it is: exit) and launch the application if it was not running.

Additionally: If the WOL event comes at random times you can still use the scheduled task approach if you configure your computer to NOT use auto-login. If you make sure to LOG OUT before you leave the computer to go to sleep, the computer will come out of sleep on the WOL event without anyone being logged in.
You can test for this in the scheduled task and only run the application if no one is logged in. This is a bit tricky though as Windows doesn't provide an easy check for this. My usual approach to this is to use `tasklist | findstr explorer`. If there are user(s) logged in you will get 1 line for each user, because each has his own copy of explorer.exe running. But if there is no one logged in there is also no explorer.exe running.

Answer (score -1):

still can't do this on Windows 10? It would be very interesting to be able to differentiate if the system starts after WOL or after Power On button.