# Virtualbox guest resume issue after host comes out of sleep

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Redhat 7.5  guest OS (virtualbox) in windows 7 host machine.

Both host and guest is working fine, but when host machine goes and comes  out of sleep, guest machine  is in pause mode...not able to resume the guest

kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an [old bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15378) that happens on all operating systems. It used to make the guest unstartable, but that apparently
was fixed and the VM is just paused.

I think that the solution would be to schedule immediately on the resume of
the host the command :

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm> resume
```

Scheduling a wake event is not that simple. See the post
[Running program only when PC start up using WOL](https://superuser.com/questions/1338575/running-program-only-when-pc-start-up-using-wol).

You will probably find the the guest clock will become out of sync after the
resume. It is perhaps better to avoid sleeps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....My problem get solved by waiting sometime after resume..Earlier i was trying to do something like pressing pause button. What you said is  right ..when host goes to sleep , it makes VM  to pause...once it resumes , it also resumes the guest , but it takes some time ( 10s of seconds)